# Function in pipe chain

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have this function where input parameters are **searched string** and **input file**. Function works with files:

```
f_highlite() {
    sed -e 's/\($1\)/\o033[91m\1\o033[39m/g' $2
}
```

Now I would like to use this function in pipe. How does it should be modified?

```
ps aux | grep java | f_highlite "Xms" -
```

PS: I'm not sure how to exactly name this question. If you have better suggestion say it. ;]

Comment: When you run your pipe chain, what do you expect to happen? What actually happens? What, if any, error messages do you get? What is the expected and actual output? Lastly, remember that variables (like `$1`) are not expanded inside single-quoted strings (for example `echo '$1'` inside a function will print the literal `$1` instead of expanding to the first argument).

Comment: I expect this function (which I bad named :] ) highlight _searched string_. For example I have loooong java command and want to highlight *Xms* parameter. I forgot rule about single-quoted strings which was correct by hek2mgl in the answer.

Comment: @waldauf Keep in mind that you need to make sure the first argument is properly escaped; building `sed` commands dynamically is not a trivial task.

Comment: @chepner Can you please give me some example which can make problem?

Comment: For example, `f_highlite "/usr/bin" -`. The `/` in the regex will prematurely terminate the search text in the `s` command. You would need to pass `'\/usr\/bin'` as the argument.

Comment: Got it! Thx. :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to use double quotes, otherwise `$1` wouldn't get expanded:

```
f_highlite() {
    sed -e "s/\($1\)/\o033[91m\1\o033[39m/g" "$2"
}
```

Btw, you need to make sure that `$1` won't contain characters that are understood by `sed` as syntax elements. For `Xms` that's fine.

---

To the topic, you can pass `-` as the second argument to the function because `sed` understands `-` as *stdin*:

```
ps aux | grep Java | f_highlite "Xms" -
```

(thanks [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935827/function-in-pipe-chain/41936037?noredirect=1#comment71052964_41936037)!)

Comment: There is no need for `xargs` here. POSIX `sed` recognizes (per [Guideline 13](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)) `-` as an input file meaning standard input.

Comment: @chepner Thanks. Also this does not work at all in it's current form because `xargs` can call executables but not a bash function. ;) Makes sense, but missed that. Just realized that... Working on a fix...

Comment: @chepner `-` works pefect! I was already preparing something with `xargs ... bash -c "f_highlight"` and `export -f`.. Using `-` is a simple solution here!

Comment: I overlooked it as a POSIX feature for a long time. I assumed it would be mentioned explicitly in the command description; I never actually read the syntax guidelines until someone (Charles Duffy?) mentioned pointed me there.

Comment: Your solution with xargs doesn't work me on RedHat: `ps aux | grep java | xargs -I "{}" f_highlite "Xms" "{}" >> xargs: f_highlite: No such file or directory`. But correction of single-quoted to double quotes works great: `ps aux | grep java | f_highlite "Xms" -` :]

Comment: @hek2mgl This memory was flushed. ;] :]]

Answer (score 0):

There are two other approaches that you might want to know about, as not all commands would support the `-` trick.

The first one is having a function that works on streams and does not take a file as input.  You can do that by removing the $2 at the end, and changing how you call the function

```
f_highlite() {
    sed -e 's/\($1\)/\o033[91m\1\o033[39m/g'
}

f_highlite <"Xms"
```

This will redirect the content of your file and connect it to the standard input of the function (and hence to that of `sed`).

The other approach is to keep your function as is (I am reusing a correction to the quoting suggested in another answer), but feed it a file by using process substitution.

```
f_highlite() {
    sed -e "s/\($1\)/\o033[91m\1\o033[39m/g" "$2"
}

f_highlite < <(<"Xms")
```

This (conceptually at least) creates a FIFO that has its input fed with the content of your file, and its output connected to the input of the function.  The key here is that `<(<"Xms")` becomes a filename (you can try printing its name to validate that).